# How to ignore Html elements with XMLPullParser?

Tags: java, android, xml

I have an xml file that is streamed to an xml parser.

The content of the xml file contains html tags, which I would like to ignore:

```
    <overview>
      <p>Situated on a peninsula halfway up the west coast of India, Mumbai (formerly Bombay) is India's economic powerhouse and home to more millionaires than any other city on the Indian sub-continent.</p>
      <p>The Portuguese established this old Hindu city as a colony in 1509.</p>
      <p>Like many Indian cities, the streets of Mumbai are congested with cattle, carts and motor vehicles and the air is thick with smog.</p>
</overview>
```

The method to parse the overview is:

```
private String readOverview(XmlPullParser parser) throws IOException, XmlPullParserException{
        parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, ns, TAG_OVERVIEW);
        String overview = readText(parser);
        parser.require(XmlPullParser.END_TAG, ns, TAG_OVERVIEW);
        return overview;
    }
```

The error is: expected: `END_TAG {null}overview (position:START_TAG <p>@6:10 in java.io.InputStreamReader@537c80f4)`.

Comment: Can't you parse those tags instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is to understand how the [XmlPullParser works](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser.html)

Once you understand it you can implement a function that finds the `<p>` tags and handles them as required. In this case making a `List<String>`

**Example:**

```
//Extract Tags
private List<String> readHtml(XmlPullParser parser) throws IOException, XmlPullParserException {

    List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
    //Required Tag is in calling function

    //holder for current line
    String curr_line = "";
    //get current tag name
    String current_tag_name = "";

    //while an end tag is not found
    while (parser.next() != XmlPullParser.END_TAG){
        //if a start tag is found continue
        if (parser.getEventType() != XmlPullParser.START_TAG){
            continue;
        }
        //get current tag
        current_tag_name = parser.getName();
        if (current_tag_name.equals(TAG_P)){
            curr_line = readText(parser);
        }
        else{
            skip(parser);
        }
        if (curr_line != null){
            result.add(curr_line);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That error is occurring because the parser is reading unmatched tags.

I needed my parser to read unmatched HTML tags without throwing an error, and this is what worked for me:

```
    parser.setFeature("http://xmlpull.org/v1/doc/features.html#relaxed", true);
```

This worked for me on emulators as far back as 4.1.1 (JellyBean).

If you want to *ignore* the HTML tags, the `CDATA` option is a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you can CDATA tags to your XML file. Then you should be able to ignore the HTML tags.

Reference: [XML Cdata](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_cdata.asp) - Explains it well